# Cannot open file, path = . flutter

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, camera

I'm trying to take a photo and save it to a custom directory in phone(or at least somewhere i can save it as .jpg or .jpeg).

I'm able to take photo but when I reach the DisplayPictureScreen page, flutter can not read the photo from directory which I defined.

here's codes:

```
ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: () async {
                try {
                  await _initializeControllerFuture;
                  final Directory extDir = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
                  final String dirPath = "${extDir.path}/media";
                  await Directory(dirPath).create(recursive: true);
                  final String filePath = "$dirPath/${_timestamp()}.jpeg";

                  final image = await _controller.takePicture();

                  print(filePath);
                  await Navigator.of(context).push(
                    MaterialPageRoute(
                      builder: (context) => DisplayPictureScreen(

                        imagePath: filePath,
                      ),
                    ),
                  );
                } catch (e) {
                  print(e);
                }
              },
              child: Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: const [Text("take photo"), Icon(Icons.camera)],
              )),


  String _timestamp() =>DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch.toString();


class DisplayPictureScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  final String imagePath;

  const DisplayPictureScreen({Key? key, required this.imagePath})
      : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var pageHeight = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
    var pageWidth = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(title: const Text('Display the Picture')),
        body: SizedBox(
          height: pageHeight,
          width: pageWidth,
          child: Image.file(
            File(
              imagePath,
            ),
            fit: BoxFit.fill,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

here is full error log :

```
The following FileSystemException was thrown resolving an image codec:
Cannot open file, path =
'/data/user/0/com.example.{myappname}/app_flutter/media/1642831675331.jpeg' (OS Error: No such file
or directory, errno = 2)

When the exception was thrown, this was the stack:
#0      _File.open.<anonymous closure> (dart:io/file_impl.dart:356:9)
<asynchronous suspension>
#3      FileImage._loadAsync (package:flutter/src/painting/image_provider.dart:890:29)
<asynchronous suspension>
(elided 2 frames from dart:async)

Path: /data/user/0/com.example.{myappname}/app_flutter/media/1642831675331.jpeg
```

I don't know where is the problem, when i use `image.path` as directory it works fine but i can't find the photo in my directory.

Comment: Where does takePicture() use filePath to save a picture to? Or who else would create a file on that path? We dont see it used to store a picture

Comment: Before you try to display a file use File.exists() and File canRead().

Comment: @blackapps You right , i didn't notice that . how should i store picture?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is your code:

```
final String dirPath = "${extDir.path}/media";
await Directory(dirPath).create(recursive: true);
final String filePath = "$dirPath/${_timestamp()}.jpeg";

final image = await _controller.takePicture();

print(filePath);
await Navigator.of(context).push(
  ...
);
```

On the first line, you declare the name of the folder you want to use.
Then you create said folder.

Then on the third line you declare the name of the file you want to use.

Then you take the picture, and immediately call `Navigator.of`, you never tell the picture it should be saved on your file path, all you do is declare the filepath variable.

I believe you can use the `.saveTo` method on the image:

```
...
final image = await _controller.takePicture();
await image.saveTo(filePath);
...
```

Comment: It's true, i didn't notice that i need to store picture. Tnx.